# UITextField inner shadow

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I want to get rid of the inner shadow of an `UITextField`.

[image: UITextField with inner shadow]

I have tried setting the shadow-alpha to `0` but it doesn't work:

```
name.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0f;
```

Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect`.

Comment: But then I get really black border lines. I want the same smooth borders. I want to achieve something like this: http://ofotopop.custhelp.com/rnt/rnw/img/enduser/zzz_iphoneapp_create_account_screen.jpg

Comment: Make a custom `UIView` with rounded corners and drop a transparent background `UITextField` on it.

Comment: @PengOne: Tried, shadow won't go away.

Comment: use a different border style on the ustom uiview

Comment: @PengOne: There is no border style that will give me grey borders with round corners and no inner shadow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution found.

```
name.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
name.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
name.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
name.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
```

I just needed to play with the border options of the layer while deactivating the old border-style.